# GLib: cannot initialize GValue [...] the value has already been initialized as '(null)'

Tags: c, glib

I spot very strange behavior using a `GValue`:

This code runs fine:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  {
    GValue value;
    g_value_init (&value, G_TYPE_STRING);
    g_value_set_string (&value, "hallo");
    gchar * strVal = g_strdup_value_contents (&value);
    g_print ("gvalue: %s\n", strVal);
    free (strVal);
    g_value_unset (&value);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, the following code spawns the warning `cannot initialize GValue with type 'gchararray', the value has already been initialized as '(null)'` in *the marked line*.

*Note*, that the only thing, that's changed, is the new block with another `GValue` inside.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  {
    GValue value;
    g_value_init (&value, G_TYPE_STRING);
    g_value_set_string (&value, "hallo"); // warning spawns here
    gchar * strVal = g_strdup_value_contents (&value);
    g_print ("gvalue: %s\n", strVal);
    free (strVal);
    g_value_unset (&value);
  }
  {
    GValue value2;
    g_value_init (&value2, G_TYPE_INT);
    g_value_set_int (&value2, 15);
    gchar * strVal = g_strdup_value_contents (&value2);
    g_print ("gvalue: %s\n", strVal);
    free (strVal);
    g_value_unset (&value2);   
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You improperly initialized `GValue`.

```
GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
```

Not initialized variables at block scope have some garbage value, which *may* happen to be invalid and trigger an assertion (or may happen to be valid and nothing happens).